Move out of Rc without clone
I had to write a simplified spike to boil down what I was trying to ask, as the actual code is a few thousand lines and many files.
Basically, I'm using a "ModelManager" that returns an Rc<Model> and a model can have a Material which has a typedefed image::RgbaImage as a field.  I'm saving the &[u8] bytes (i think?, it's behind the datastructure in the image crate) of the image data directly in the field.  Essentially, I need access to this data.  Ideally, I'm not loading from disk every time I need it.  I'd also really like to avoid cloning it everywhere as well.  Not really sure what to do here.  I'm welcome to restructuring suggestions too.
Here's the code, with the error:
use std::{
    fs::{
        metadata, File
    }, io::Read, path::PathBuf,
    rc::Rc,
};

use ash::vk::{
    BufferCreateInfo,
    BufferUsageFlags,
    SharingMode,
};

use image::RgbaImage;

pub type TextureImage = RgbaImage;

struct Material {
    texture: TextureImage,
}

struct Model {
    //materials: Vec<Material>, 
    materials: Material,
}

impl Model {
    fn new() -> Rc<Self> {
        Rc::new(
            Self{
                materials: Material::new(&PathBuf::from("yolo")),
            }
        )
    }
 }

impl Material {
    fn new(tex_loc: &PathBuf) -> Self {
        let mut file = File::open(&tex_loc).map_err(|e| e.to_string()).unwrap();
        let metadata = metadata(&tex_loc).map_err(|e| e.to_string()).unwrap();
        let mut buffer = vec![0; metadata.len() as usize];
        file.read(&mut buffer).map_err(|e| e.to_string()).unwrap();
        let texture = image::load_from_memory(&buffer).map_err(|e| e.to_string()).unwrap()
            .to_rgba8();
        Material{texture}
     }
 }

 fn main() {
     let model = Model::new();
     //let mat = Material::new(&PathBuf::from("yolo"));
     let tex_image = &model.materials.texture;
     let (width, height) = tex_image.dimensions();
     //let image_extent = vk::Extent2D { width, height };
     let image_data = tex_image.into_raw();  //Here's the error, copied below
     let image_buffer_info = BufferCreateInfo {
         size: (42 * image_data.len()) as u64,
         usage: BufferUsageFlags::TRANSFER_SRC,
         sharing_mode: SharingMode::EXCLUSIVE,
         ..Default::default()
     };
 }

Here's the error:
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*tex_image` which is behind a shared reference
   --> spikes/src/bin/references.rs:55:22
    |
55  |     let image_data = tex_image.into_raw();
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^ ---------- `*tex_image` moved due to this method call
    |                      |
    |                      move occurs because `*tex_image` has type `ImageBuffer<Rgba<u8>, Vec<u8>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    |

I'm still fairly new to Rust but I fear my code is devolving into needless complication trying to get this to work.  One thing I was thinking of doing is writing a "TextureManger" or  something that maintains an Rc and letting that be a field in the Material.
TLDR; How do I maintain the TextureImage data such that I can use it multiple times without copying/cloning?
Goes without saying, this will crash, don't run it.

You can't get an owned Container from a Rc (unless it's not shared) without cloning. You can get a shared reference with as_raw

Dereferencing  the raw pointer is unsafe.  I'd like to minimize that too.  I might have the texture field be a Weak and just handout Rc's.

ImageBuffer::as_raw gives you a &Container, not a raw pointer.

Your example seems pretty poor since you aren't even using the ownership of image_data (you're just calling .len()). Do you need ownership? If so, what do you intend for model to look like after you take ownership of the texture? Is the model destroyed? or leave a default texture in its place?

oh.... yeah, that might work, sorry didn't realize what you meant as first, one line change:
let image_data = tex_image.as_raw();
I have one more use of it later in the code:
image_slice.copy_from_slice(&image_data);

Thanks @cafce25, it was a one line solution:
let image_data = tex_image.into_raw(); needed to be changed to:
let image_data = tex_image.as_raw();  I'll go through RgbaImage and image::Container to better understand this.
